# Select2 is not working in Amazon Web Services (AWS)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jquery-select2

I have used select2 in my mvc web application. But problem is, select2 is working fine on localhost but when uploaded on AWS, it does not work. I tried to give references of online cdn too but it also never worked for me. When I open inspect, I see select2 js has worked fine but select2 css is not working to load select2 design.

Comment: Please provide more information, have you validated any errors in your browsers console?

Comment: No, there is no error in console

Comment: And you've validated the code is there from the browser?

Comment: If its modifiying an existing file make sure to try clearing browser cache

Comment: Right click on browser, select "Inspect Element"-> Select "console" tab, check for errors and give more details.

Comment: I see it is not taking the refernce of select2 on online server but locally it is working correctly. So i gave online cdn and now its working fine.